# Thermodynamic Entropy seems to be contradictory

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, ideal-gas

For an ideal gas the entropy change with energy is inversely proportional to temperature:

This must yield:

$$S=\frac 3 2 k_B  \ N  ln(T)$$

For various reasons, this equation is hard to find.

However we know when temperate is $0$ the entropy is $0$, yet the above equation yields

$$S = -\infty$$

I am having difficulty figuring out where my logic is wrong.

Comment: For one, you can't expect it to be a gas all the way down to low temperatures, you can have phase changes which alter the entropy relationship

Comment: Point taken, but I am querying the equation rather than the practicality.  I think most people here are familiar with the statistical mechanics derivation of entropy.  If we confine the issue to this only, then it is clear that entropy will go to 0.  That is all molecules will be at 0 energy-state so p is 1 and ln(p) is 0.  But an alternative derivation will give the change of entropy with beta is energy. and beta is 1/ (K T) which will still end up with entropy =-infinity.  So somewhere there is a mistake in my logic. (from a mathematical viewpoint).

Comment: It is an ideal gas, at the end. At low T, ie reduced distance between particles, the ideal gas isn't a model anymore.

Comment: After your second comments. Out of classical realm Fermi-Dirac and Bose-Einstein statistics. Else the ideal gas doesn't work as in above comment.

Comment: That definition of entropy is only true for ideal gases, and ideal gases are a high temperature approximation (i.e., the classical limit). Of course you get nonsensical results when applying a high temperature model to low temperatures.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, the correct expression for a classical ideal gas is
$$
\frac{S}{k_BN} = \frac{3}{2}\ln(T) + \Phi(\rho)
$$
where $\Phi(\rho)$ is a function only of the number density (containing also information about the mass of the particles).

Such a function is not inversely proportional to the temperature but it is an increasing function of $T$, the logarithm being a strictly increasing function of its argument.

As far as finite and high temperature limit is concerned, this dependence shows no problem. On the basis of general thermodynamic considerations, entropy must be a monotonically increasing function.

As you notice, there is a problem with the third law of thermodynamics. This is a well known problem of the classical Statistical Mechanics of the perfect gas and it is related to the fact that the discretization of  classical phase space is in a way artificial in classical mechanics and only a proper quantum mechanical treatment of the perfect gas restores a physical behavior of entropy at very low temperatures.

From the practical point of view, this inadequacy of the classical formula is not a problem because, by decreasing temperature, all real systems, due to interactions,  stop to behave like a perfect gas much before quantum effects enter into play.

Comment: Wow! That's a very good answer. I do not understand though how is S(T) directly proportional to T in the expression your wrote. If that were the case, I would expect to be able to write $S(T) = aT$ where $a$ is a constant. What am I missing?

Comment: @tttt  I should had written more clearly: *difference of entropy* at different temperatures is directly proportional to the difference of temperature. I was implicitly taken for granted that  the observable quantity is  a difference of entropy, since in any case entropy is defined within an arbitrary constant (like energy).

Comment: In that case I get $S(T_2)-S(T_1) = \frac{3}{2}\ln \left( \frac{T_2}{T_1} \right)$ which is not proportional to $T_2-T_1$. Did I goof somewhere?

Comment: @tttt  No, you're right, I see that went too fast and I made a mistake. I'll correct my answer: $S(T)$ is linearly increasing with $ln(T)$ (the key point of my original observation remains: the inverse proportionality as in the OP question, would imply a decrasing function of $T$).

Comment: Ok nice. Indeed, that's a reason why I think your answer is a very good one.

Answer (score 1):

It is a sin to write a non-linear function (other than a simple power) of a dimensional quantity.  $log(T)$ is ill-defined, but  $log(T/T_{ref})$ would be proper.  But what to use for ${{T}_{ref}}$?  The answer is not obvious.

To calculate the absolute entropy, you may use the Sackur-Tetrode equation.  Entropy per molecule is the logarithm of the number of states, which can be calculated as the volume per molecule in position space, multiplied by the “volume” in momentum space, divided by $h^3$.   The “volume” in position space can be calculated as $\int{{{d}^{3}}p}\exp (-{{p}^{2}}/2mkT)\sim {{T}^{3/2}}$, this being a high-*T* approximation that can be justified by a detailed QM calculation for particles in a box.